# How to change list text with dropdown selection using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to Javascript and I am trying to update the HTML list below to display certain values depending on the dropdown value I select. However, when I change the dropdown options, the list is not updating with the correct dynamic values. I tried checking the console log but no errors are displaying either.

Any tips on how I can get this working? I would prefer to stick with using vanilla Javascript for now since I am still trying to learn it.

```js
let sel = document.getElementById("num-of-servings");

function servingSize(sel) {
  selValue = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
  selText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

  if (sel === "first") {
    document.getElementById("first-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " pounds of beef";
    document.getElementById("second-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of salt";
    document.getElementById("third-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of pepper";
  } else if (sel === "second") {
    document.getElementById("first-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " pounds of beef";
    document.getElementById("second-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of salt";
    document.getElementById("third-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of pepper";
  } else if (sel === "third") {
    document.getElementById("first-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " pounds of beef";
    document.getElementById("second-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of salt";
    document.getElementById("third-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of pepper";
  } else if (sel === "fourth") {
    document.getElementById("first-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " pounds of beef";
    document.getElementById("second-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of salt";
    document.getElementById("third-ingredient").innerHTML = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of pepper";
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="1" id="num-of-servings" onchange="servingSize(this)">
  <option value="first">4</option>
  <option value="second">6</option>
  <option value="third">8</option>
  <option value="fourth">12</option>
</select>
<ul>
  <li id="first-ingredient">1 pound of beef</li>
  <li id="second-ingredient">1 teaspoon of salt</li>
  <li id="third-ingredient">1 teaspoon of pepper</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The param of `servingSize` consists of a bunch of other properties including `value`.

If you want to get `value`, you should get it from `e.value`.

*Side note values from fields/HTML elements are strings by default, so you need to parse them to numbers for number operations.*

```js
let sel = document.getElementById("num-of-servings");

function servingSize(e) {
  const sel = e.value;
  const selText = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].innerText);

  if (sel === "first") {
    document.getElementById("first-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " pounds of beef";
    document.getElementById("second-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of salt";
    document.getElementById("third-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of pepper";
  } else if (sel === "second") {
    document.getElementById("first-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " pounds of beef";
    document.getElementById("second-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of salt";
    document.getElementById("third-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of pepper";
  } else if (sel === "third") {
    document.getElementById("first-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " pounds of beef";
    document.getElementById("second-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of salt";
    document.getElementById("third-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of pepper";
  } else if (sel === "fourth") {
    document.getElementById("first-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " pounds of beef";
    document.getElementById("second-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of salt";
    document.getElementById("third-ingredient").innerText = (1 * selText) + " teaspoons of pepper";
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="1" id="num-of-servings" onchange="servingSize(this)">
  <option value="first">4</option>
  <option value="second">6</option>
  <option value="third">8</option>
  <option value="fourth">12</option>
</select>
<ul>
  <li id="first-ingredient">1 pound of beef</li>
  <li id="second-ingredient">1 teaspoon of salt</li>
  <li id="third-ingredient">1 teaspoon of pepper</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your response! When I make the changes to the function then test it, the value in the list will update only once, but will not update again if I change the Number of Servings. For example, if I choose "6" in the dropdown, it will update the list to "4 pounds of beef", "4 teaspoons", etc. If I choose "8" in the dropdown, the list will still stay the same.

Comment: hi @patn237, thanks for your feedback. I was figuring out it was a small problem with getting selected-option text. You can check it out again!

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not working because in `if` condition it looks like you are checking the DOM element itself. If you replace `sel` in `if` conditions by `selValue` it will work as you expected.

It can be done without `if else` conditions. You just have to get the `text` of selected option and display the results.

```js
let sel = document.getElementById("num-of-servings");

function servingSize(sel) {
  let firstIngredient = document.getElementById("first-ingredient");
  let secondIngredient = document.getElementById("second-ingredient");
  let thirdIngredient = document.getElementById("third-ingredient");

  const selText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
  
  firstIngredient.innerText = `${selText} pounds of beef`;
  secondIngredient.innerText = `${selText} teaspoons of salt`;
  thirdIngredient.innerText = `${selText} teaspoons of pepper`;
}
```

```html
<select name="1" id="num-of-servings" onchange="servingSize(this)">
  <option value="first">4</option>
  <option value="second">6</option>
  <option value="third">8</option>
  <option value="fourth">12</option>
</select>
<ul>
  <li id="first-ingredient">1 pound of beef</li>
  <li id="second-ingredient">1 teaspoon of salt</li>
  <li id="third-ingredient">1 teaspoon of pepper</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, modifying `sel` to `selValue` in my if else statements worked as expected! Your code changes also worked as well! Thank you!! I'll go with your changes though since there is no repeated code which is what I was going to work towards next anyways. 

Dumb question, if I needed to test the output of a variable inside a function, how would I need to write that in `console.log()`? I was trying to test the variables inside a function to see if they would return the correct value, but it says selText is not defined. 
 
`console.log(servingSize(selText));`

Comment: if you are using `console.log()`  inside the `function servingSize()` then you don't need `console.log(servingSize(selText));` just `console.log(selText)` will do the thing. if  you are getting an error, then it might be problem of scope. Like if you are using `selText` outside the function.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply! Okay good to know. I was just wondering if there was a way to test variables that were in the scope of the function without having to move them outside the scope. When I do `console.log(selText)`, it returns undefined.